# Deploy frontend and backend in Render

Tags: reactjs, render

I am trying to deploy my app in Render. I have Front End files in their own folder inside the root directory along with the server side files/folders. Can I do it like this or do I need a Render deploy for front end and 1 for backend.

The deploy has run but when I go to URL it displays some text (which must be coming from me because there is a spelling mistake - can't find where) and nothing else. No errors i console.

I have set up a database and think have environment variables set correctly but don't think this is the problem because nothing is displaying. Wondering if this is because my front end files are in their own folder. When I start my app locally I have to run nodemon app.js in the root directory, navigate to front end folder and run npm start to start backend. I can't find any settings on Render that runs the npm start.

Thanks for any advice